# How could I get exact timezone info from string, like +08:00 from "Asia/Shanghai" using golang?

Tags: go, timezone

I want to get exact timezone from string, like +08:00 from "Asia/Shanghai"

Comment: See [How to construct time.Time with timezone offset in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552101/how-to-construct-time-time-with-timezone-offset-in-go/54552153#54552153), also [Why is time.Parse not using the timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287664/why-is-time-parse-not-using-the-timezone/50287766#50287766)

Comment: I see how to do it:    location, _ := time.LoadLocation(s)
    name, offset := time.Now().In(location).Zone()
    fmt.Printf("name:%#v, offset:%#v\n", name, offset)

Comment: The UTC offset is only defined at a particular date and time (it often changes twice a year due to daylight savings time, for instance). Use [Time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) to print the offset for a time.Time value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [LoadLocation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation) function.

Answer (score -2):

```
location, _ := time.LoadLocation(s)
name, offset := time.Now().In(location).Zone()
// offset is what I want
fmt.Printf("name:%#v, offset:%#v\n", name, offset)
```

Comment: Please take some minute to add some explanation to your answer. It will improve your answer for future users.