# IST time zone error in time package go golang

Tags: go, time

I need to convert any given time zone in RFC3339 format to system time in RFC3339 format.But for few time zone like IST it is throwing the error and the time is still in UTC.
For conversion which function service as better? time.parse or time.In.

I tried to convert the UTC to IST but it failed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    //now time
    now := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("now ", now)
    zone, _ := now.Zone()
    fmt.Println("zone->", zone)

    ll, llerr := time.LoadLocation(zone)
    fmt.Println("Load Location", ll, llerr)
    // Convert the given time to system based time zone
    t, err := time.ParseInLocation(time.RFC3339, "2017-04-25T23:03:00Z", ll)
    fmt.Println("t - parsein", t)
    fmt.Println("err - parsein", err)
    //fmt.Println("t2 - parse", t.In(ll))

}
```

Error : `unknown time zone IST`

Expected: Need to convert any time zone to system time zone.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [Why is time.Parse not using the timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287664/why-is-time-parse-not-using-the-timezone/50287766#50287766)

Answer (score 0):

You can't load Indian IST time zone by that name because the name "IST" is ambiguous. It could mean India, Ireland, Israel, etc. time zones, which have different zone offsets and rules. For details, see [Why is time.Parse not using the timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287664/why-is-time-parse-not-using-the-timezone/50287766#50287766)

If IST is your local zone, the [`time.Local`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Location) variable will denote that time zone. If you have a [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time), you can "switch" to another zone using [`Time.In()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In), also [`Time.Local()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Local) returns the time in your local zone.

Of course this code would "break" when ran in another zone. To make sure it behaves the same everywhere, load the Indian IST zone explicitly like this:

```
loc, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(time.Now())
fmt.Println(time.Now().In(loc))
```

On the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JBxQWNY3ySf) it will output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
2009-11-11 04:30:00 +0530 IST
```

Comment: Okay, but we still don`t know which locations time zones have same issue. Because the same code has to be executed in many places and what if we hit the same issue.
To avoid this, i planned to take it from time.Zone() itself but again it is not helping.
The above solution solves IST issue as we know the exact term . So we need it to find out with help of system time itself. So any way to do so.

Comment: @kish I don't understand what you mean.